# Media Query is not being detected in FF 35 ONLY

Tags: html, css

For some reason the Media query is not being detected on FireFox 35.0.1 only. This is an excerpt of the media query :

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1264px){
    #home{
        height:900px ; 
        background-size:cover;
         }
    #contactus{
        height:900px ;
        background: url(../img/bg3_chk.png) no-repeat 86% 18.65px;
        }
    p.homeCopy{
        bottom:430px;
        }
    h1.contacthline{
        top:170.1px ;
        }         
 }
```

I have checked the issue with some other questions, however still the problem persists, in one of the answer the problem was that the person did a syntactical mistake, while some other answers say that the FF renders viewport size a bit differently than Chrome and Internet Explorer. So I actually do not understand why the media query is being ignored in FF 35. If you could give me possible solutions or insights as to how to solve it or why is it happening, I would really appreciate it. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media (max-width:1264px){
    #home{
        height:900px ; 
        background-size:cover;
         }
    #contactus{
        height:900px ;
        background: url(../img/bg3_chk.png) no-repeat 86% 18.65px;
        }
    p.homeCopy{
        bottom:430px;
        }
    h1.contacthline{
        top:170.1px ;
        }         
 }
```

Try it.

Comment: Checked it out, the problem still persists. Any thoughts ?

Comment: send the link plz to check it

Comment: Alright I will send you the link once I set it up. or do you know a better place than JsFiddle where I can showcase my problem effectively ?

Comment: @Jaswinder: Please explain what is wrong and how and why your answer solves it. There is no need to repost _all_ the parts that are not relevant to the solution.